# WCF Json Rest service not hitting the Methods

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, wcf-binding

I am writing a WCF service, (json REST) and I have it working fine when using the wcftestclient.exe

When I run that test tool it triggers my break points while debugging and everything **works** as expected.

but, when using a browser to navigate to the the service and method, no break point is triggered. it seems as though the request isnt even getting to the code.

I receieve no errors on when navigating with web browser to the service, it just doesn't get any data, or trigger the break points.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I have read and tried many many different configurations found in answers to similar questions, but nothing seems to work.

Many thanks for any help, I've posted my code below.

Martyn

I have setup:
ServiceContract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<Country> GetAllCountries();
```

The Service CLass:

```
    public List<Country> GetAllCountries()
    {
        ControlServiceRepository rep = new ControlServiceRepository();
        return rep.GetAllCountries().ToList() ;
    }
```

and my web config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="OmniData" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:55641/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ControlService.IOmniData" behaviorConfiguration="rest" />
      </service>
    </services>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="rest">
            <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="ServiceConfig">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Are you calling the service from the same domain?

Comment: I'm current just trying to get it working through visual studio, i have uploaded it to iis7 and it is exactly the same. Webbrowser call is: http://localhost:55641/OmniData.svc/GetAllStores

Comment: `GetAllStores` or `GetAllCountries` ?

Comment: lol, god help me... too long looking at this, GetAllCountries

Comment: You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) while your test tool is running and see how it calls your service

Comment: that's extremely helpful, its actually showing that my call is 400 bad request. so it must be something in the web.config I've got wrong. at the very least this is another direction to google, plus a good tool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working in the end by deleting all the end points in the config and using

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(OmniData)));
```

if anyone else has issues, this is even easier than setting up end points because you can just specify the type of responses and end points within the classes themselves.

so:

Add a global.asax if one does exist and include this:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(OmniData)));
        }
```

decorate your Service class with

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

here is mine:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class OmniData : IOmniData
{
  public Country[] GetAllCountries()
  {
    ControlServiceRepository rep = new ControlServiceRepository();
    return rep.GetAllCountries().ToArray() ;
  }
}
```

then the interface you setup your endpoing and types using WebGet or WebInvoke

```
public interface IOmniData
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "OmniData/GetAllCountries", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        Country[] GetAllCountries();
    }
```

the UriTemplate is the end point, so to access the method you would use: http://MyService.com/OmniData/GetAllCountries

and finally, web config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
      <service name="OmniData">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:55641"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ControlService.IOmniData" behaviorConfiguration="rest" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="rest">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Alot of help from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx)

but, importantly for what I wanted, json results, you need to make sure:
automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" is in there so it will use the response format specified in the interface. Otherwise you end up with XML instead.

hopefully this helps someone else

And thanks again for fiddler!

Martyn

Comment: I am sorry, but where to add "RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(OmniData)));" ??

Answer (score 2):

I think there are some things missing in your contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetAllCountries", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
List<Country> GetAllCountries();
```

Try this.Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had almost this exact line, I altered it to WebGet following one of many different answers. Same problem with this. thanks for the help, I'll try pretty much anything at the moment :p